# Get Specific Key/Value From Associative Array and Store them as Variable

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I need to access the specific `key/value` of associative array as variables using `foreach` loop. Getting `key/value` pairs of all data in the `array` is not a problem. The problem is with getting a **specific** `key/value`. Take the code below for example

```
<?php

$data = [

    'person1' => 
        [
            'id' => 101,
            'firstName' => 'John',
            'LastName' => 'Smith'

        ],

        'person2' => 
        [
            'id' => 102,
            'firstName' => 'Mary',
            'LastName' => 'Smart'

        ]

];
```

I can get `key/value` pairs of all data in the `array` by the code below:

```
foreach($data as $firstKey => $firstValue){
    foreach ($firstValue as $secondKey => $secondValue) {
        echo $secondKey. ": ". $secondValue . "<br />";


    }
}
```

The above code is not exactly what I want. 
I want to get specific `key/value` for example, I want to get only the key/value of only the `id`s.

So I tried something like this:

```
$specificId = null;
foreach($data as $firstKey => $firstValue){
    foreach ($firstValue as $secondKey => $secondValue) {
        if($secondKey == 'id'){ // using if statement to get key/value pair of person's id
            $specificId = $secondValue; //storing the specific ids as variable
            echo $secondKey . ": ". $specificId . "<br>"; 

        }

    }
}


?>
```

The above code seems to work but if I also want to get `key/value` for only  `firstName`, then, I have to write another `if` statement. 
I will end up writing so many `if` statements in the `foreach` loop. Do you know another way I can write lesser code to get specific `key/value` pairs?

There are many similar questions like mine but the answer I am looking for is not the objective of any of those questions.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You want to store every value in an individual variable?  Then what (safe) alternative could there be but conditional checks for each key?  And why copy every array value into a separate variable when you can reference them directly inside the array?

Comment: Well @Matt S, I thought I could get one variable to store every value. for instance just the way `$secondValue` holds multiple values. But as it seems now, It appears one variable to hold multiple values is just not ideal. Also I copied every array value into a variable because I planned to use the variable outside the `if` Statement if possible

Comment: "I thought I could get one variable to store every value."  Yes, that's called an array.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php There's no reason you can't reference your `$data` array or subarrays within it outside of an `if`.

Comment: In my example in the OP, if you echo `$specificId` outside the  `if` statement, It outputs only one value which is the last value because first value is overwritten by the second value. Example the `$specificId` outputs two `Id`s namely `101` and `102` in the `if` statement but only `102` outside the `if statement`

Comment: Though this has been answered, but I'm wondering, why couldn't you simply use the inner array, as what it is, an *array*? I mean, if you wanted to compare to a specific id, just do: `if ($firstValue['id'] === $specificId) { ...` skipping the inner loop completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($data as $firstKey => $firstValue) {
       echo array_keys($firstValue, $firstValue['id'])[0].': '.$firstValue['id'].'</br>';
       echo array_keys($firstValue, $firstValue['firstName'])[0].': '.$firstValue['firstName'].'</br>';
}
```

you can just call the associative array key from the array

> This outputs key and values

Comment: thanks. This gives us the `values`. How about the `keys`. I am asking for the `keys' in the case where you do not know the `values`

Comment: you want the key as variable also?

Comment: @bityo kazi, yes

Comment: I updated my answer. Check it out if it serves your purpose @PrinceBrucex

Comment: Yes, that is awesome. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

array_intersect_key should do the job just fine:

```
$results=[];
foreach($data as $name => $attriubtesPerson)
{
    $results[$name] = array_intersect_key($attributesPerson, ['id' => null, 'firstName' => null]);
}
```

documentation can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

Comment: Hi @Transitive, thanks for response but I don't see how  `array_intersect_key` works just fine in this case

Comment: array_intersect_key returns all values where the key in the first input array is the same as any of the values in the second input array.
This means you do not need to branch with multiple if clauses just to check if a key exists and then perform your logic on them. Now you can just list all the keys you want to fetch from the array and perform you logic in the resulting set

Comment: The example you have provided in the answer outputs two empty arrays.
Can you check and write example that well demonstrates what you are saying?

Comment: I am so sorry, I made the mistake of not comparing the keys with each other. It intersects the key values with one another, not the values of the second array input.
My apologies, I edited the code snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

To access specific key values you need to convert the array to Json and access it just like a normal object.

```js
    $data = [
        'person1' => 
            [
                'id' => 101,
                'firstName' => 'John',
                'LastName' => 'Smith'
            ],
            'person2' => 
            [
                'id' => 102,
                'firstName' => 'Mary',
                'LastName' => 'Smart'
            ]
    ];
    $obj = json_decode(json_encode($data));

    //to access key=values directly

    echo $obj->person1->firstname;

   //to access all firstname only
    foreach($obj as $o){
      echo $o->firstName;
    }
```